# How to add Attribute in code behind?

Tags: asp.net

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        HtmlTableRow tr = (HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("itemTemplate"); //tr of table
        if (tr != null)
        {
            foreach (Control c in tr.Controls)
            {
                HtmlTableCell cell = (HtmlTableCell)c;  //td of table.
                if (cell != null)
                {
                    cell.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.class='fontBolding'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is part of the template of my listview,and my "fontBolding" is definded in a single .css file and I used it in my current page.
But how can I set the attribute.

Comment: onmouseover is also attribute.... so you can set it in the same way by `cell.Attributes.Add`

Comment: You could use tr.Cells instead of tr.Controls. This way you don't have to cast c to HtmlTableCell.

Comment: "But how can I set the attribute." - What attribute?

Comment: Might help `cell.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.className='fontBolding'");`

Comment: So you mean, that this line does not work for you?

Comment: Hi,Jenny,you got the point, it didn't work,and it render unwanted in the browser,such as:

Comment: it render such as: <td onmouseover="this.class=&#39;fontbolding&#39;"

Comment: Hi,satpal,it does not work either,i always render :'fontbolding' as &#39;fontbolding&#39;